# Where can I find the header files to the standard library on the system?

Tags: c, unix, header-files, standard-library, libc

Where can I find those standard library (`stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`) which I use daily on the system?

Comment: You'd have to tell us which O/S!

Comment: Linux? `/use/include`

Comment: When your OS is windows, you also have to tell us your development environment and compiler, because they all store them in different places.

Comment: [GCC Document for search PATH](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)

Comment: Tap `Windows` key and type `stdio.h`, on Windows. Use `find / -name stdio.h` in Linux.

Comment: If you write code on linux with vim, you just move cursor to stdio.h/stdlib.h, then type gf.

Comment: I am working mostly on linux / MacOSX

Comment: `*.h` files are called "header files" and are text files, mainly prototyping (parts of) what a library exports. There can be more than one header for one library. Libraries contain the implementation of what the header files describe. The latter are binary files.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, they are usually stored inside `/usr/include` directory. Under Windows (and Visual Studio), they are located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include`  (may differ if you changed default install location).

Also, file search (`find`, `locate`, as Christian suggested, or Windows Explorer search) is a good way to find these files.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in a *nix environment such as Linux, BSD and Mac OS X  the directory "/usr/include" is a good start. If you did not find them there try the locate command.

# locate stdio.h

If you are not able to *locate* those files, update your mlocate database (# sudo updatedb) and then try a the localization again.

Comment: On Mac OS X, when I check `string.h` I see definition like this `char    *stpncpy(char *, const char *, size_t) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);` Where to trace down the `_OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING` function.